# What is difference between hasmoreelements and hasmoretokens in stringtokenizer java?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am very much confused between hasmoreelements and hasmoretokens method of stringtokenizer.

I want to know what's the difference

Can anybody clear my confusion?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like that method exists just to conform to the [Enumeration interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html).

Answer (score 7):

> I want to know what's the difference

From the [Java API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#hasMoreElements%28%29):

> hasMoreElements()
>
> Returns the same value as the hasMoreTokens method. It exists so that this class can implement the Enumeration interface.

There is no difference from a functional perspective.

`hasMoreElements()` needs to be there because `StringTokenizer` implements the `Enumeration` interface.

Answer (score 1):

As per API

public boolean hasMoreTokens()

> Returns true if more tokens exist.

public boolean hasMoreElements()

> Returns true if the Enumeration has more elements.

**So Bottem line is they are same and It supports Enumeration**

Answer (score 1):

There seems be no difference as the javadoc says:

> boolean  hasMoreElements() 
>             Returns the same value as the hasMoreTokens method. hasMoreElements.**It exists so that this class can implement the
>   Enumeration interface.**
>
> boolean  hasMoreTokens() 
>             Tests if there are more tokens available from this tokenizer's string.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

```
boolean hasMoreElements()
Returns the same value as the hasMoreTokens method.

boolean hasMoreTokens()
Tests if there are more tokens available from this tokenizer's string.
```

Answer (score 0):

hasMoreElements returns the same value as the hasMoreTokens method. It exists so that this class can implement the Enumeration interface.